# Ubuntu installer and start

Tags: ubuntu

почему то появляется такая ошибка при запуске убунту, не понимаю в чем проблема
[image: ubuntu installer]

Comment: [слишком глобальный вопрос](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=kernel+panic+no+init+found)

Comment: из первых результатов поиска, предложенных выше, вот [этот](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/init.html), пожалуй, наиболее адекватный.

Comment: Оперативы виртуалке сколько выделил? Дай хотя бы гиг.